Does peft train newly initialized weights?
When using peft to fine-tune a pretrained model e.g., DistilBert, you need to specify the target_modules. In case of DistilBert, typically, the attention weights are targeted. Example:
lora_config = LoraConfig(
    r=8, # Rank Number
    lora_alpha=32, # Alpha (Scaling Factor)
    lora_dropout=0.05, # Dropout Prob for Lora
    target_modules=["q_lin", "k_lin","v_lin"], # Which layer to apply LoRA, usually only apply on MultiHead Attention Layer
    bias='none',
    task_type=TaskType.SEQ_CLS # Seqence to Classification Task
)

my question, when finetuning a pretrained model on a downstream task, you initialize a new layer (like classification layer) which is not pre-trained and have random weights, does peft also freeze this layer or does it optimize it?

When a new task-specific layer, like a classification head, is added to the pretrained model, it is not frozen by default. This layer typically starts with random weights and is trained/optimized along with the LoRA parameters. So basically PEFT focuses on freezing the backbone of the model and it doesn't include any added layers.
You can easily verify the parameters in your model like this:
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    print(name, param.requires_grad)

The classification head will have requires_grad=True

All Parameter-Efficient Fine-Tuning (PEFT) methods train a small number of extra model parameters while keeping the parameters of the pretrained model frozen. There are different methods of PEFT, including prompt-tuning, prefix-tuning, and LoRA, among others. In the case of LoRA, which is the method you are using, it tracks changes that should be applied to model weights using two low-rank matrices. The target_modules option specifies which layers of the model will be modified to incorporate the LoRA technique. For example, q_lin refers to the linear transformation that computes the query vectors in a multi-head attention mechanism. In your code, you specify that LoRA should be applied to optimize the parameters of this layer. Thus, LoRA adapters (the low-rank matrices that track weight changes to be applied to the targeted weights) will be added to this layer (and any other specified target layers) and they will be optimized during fine-tuning.
